# System of linear nonhomogeneous fourth order ODE's

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system $(*)$ of two fourth order linear ODE's:

$$
\left(\frac{f''(x) - g''(x)}{\alpha(x)}\right)'' = a (f,g)\beta_1(x) + b(f,g) \beta_2 (x), 
$$

$$
\left(\frac{f''(x) - g''(x)}{\alpha(x)}\right)'' = c(f,g) \beta_1(x) + d(f,g) \beta_2 (x). 
$$

where

- $f$ and $g$ are unknown,
- $\beta_1$, and $\beta_2$ are given,
- $a(\cdot, \cdot),b(\cdot, \cdot),c(\cdot, \cdot),d(\cdot, \cdot)$ are functionals: maps from, say, $C^4(\mathbb{R}) \times C^4(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

> Problem: Characterize the solutions $f$ and $g$.

One possible way to go about this is:

1. Fix constants $a,b,c,d$.  Find corresponding solutions $f(a,b,c,d)$ and $g(a,b,c,d)$. (Notation: $a(\cdot, \cdot)$ is a map and $a$ is a constant.)
2. Solve the system of 4 equations $a( f(a,b,c,d), g(a,b,c,d)) = a$, 
   $b( f(a,b,c,d), g(a,b,c,d)) = b$, etc, and find the value $a(f^*,g^*)$ ($b(f^*,g^*)$, etc) of the functional $a(\cdot, \cdot)$ ($b(\cdot, \cdot)$, etc.) at the solutions $(f^*, g^*)$.

So, carrying out step 1, we're looking at the system

$$
\left(\frac{f''(x) - g''(x)}{\alpha(x)}\right)'' = a \beta_1(x) + b\beta_2 (x), \quad (1)
$$

$$
\left(\frac{f''(x) - g''(x)}{\alpha(x)}\right)'' = c \beta_1(x) + d \beta_2 (x) \; \; \quad (2)
$$

where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are constants. There are now two subcases:

1. $\beta_1(x)$ and $\beta_2(x)$ are linearly independent. So $a = c$ and 
   $b = d$, and one is looking at, say, just Equation (1).
2. $\beta_1(x)$ and $\beta_2(x)$ are linearly dependent. Then one is looking at an equation of the form

$$
\left(\frac{f''(x) - g''(x)}{\alpha(x)}\right)'' = k \beta_1(x). 
$$

In any case, we have a linear inhomogeneous ODE of the form

$$
\frac{1}{\alpha} h'' - 2\frac{\alpha'}{\alpha^2} h' - \frac{\alpha^2 \alpha'' - 2 \alpha \alpha'^2}{\alpha^4} h =
\begin{cases}
\beta_1(x) + b\beta_2 (x) \quad \mbox{case 1}\\
k \beta_1(x) \quad \quad \quad \quad \; \: \hfill \mbox{case 2}
\end{cases},
$$

where $h = (f - g)''$.

**Question:** The above equation is solvable only up to $f-g$, correct? If so, is there any structure one can impose on the system $(*)$ that would allow a characterization of $(f,g)$?

Comment: Is $\beta=\gamma$?

Comment: @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis Good point. See edits above.

Comment: The left-hand-sides of the two equations are equal. How can $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be different?